# VS LoadTest does not save results into the SQL Server

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I am performing a Load Test using VS, but the results are not saved in SQL Server.

When I run the test, the table `LoadTestRun` is populated with data, but when the test is done, the table `LoadTestTestSummaryData` stays empty.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As pre-steps you need for Performance and Load Testing with Visual Studio:

1. install and configure Visual Studio ULTIMATE.
2. SQL Server (e.g SQLEXPRESS 2012) (both SERVER & MANAGER) [e.g.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vng0P8Gfx2g)

Be sure that SQLEXPRESS service *is running*. You can run SQL Server Configuration Manager and start it manually. Be careful for the correct INSTANCE_NAME. Also in Task Manager > Services. Next go to Start menu and find VS2012 Cross Tools Command Prompt. Type the following:

```
cd C:\ Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
```

and

```
SQLCMD /S localhost\sqlexpress /i loadtestresultsrepository.sql
```

This will create Load test DB schema that is required for VS 2012 Load tests.

1. On the Load Test toolbar, choose Manage Test Controllers. The Manage Test Controllers dialog box is displayed.
2. In the Load Test Results Connection String, click the browse button (…) to display the Connection Properties dialog box.

*Note*

If you change the connection string for a controller, then you must select the controller.

3. In Server Name, type localhost\sqlexpress or the name of the server that you used in step 2 such as ContosoServer1.
4. Under Log on to the server, choose Use Windows Authentication.
5. Under Connect to a database, choose Select or enter a database name. Select LoadTest from the drop-down list box.
6. Choose OK.

All these steps has to be executed in order to get the proper level of integration between VS, SQL ( and maybe Excel for reporting). I suspect that

> table LoadTestTestSummaryData stays empty.

because you are missing one of the above mentioned steps.

Comment: I have already done everything in your post and `LoadTestTestSummaryData' is empty and `LoadTestRun` is full with data.

Comment: Yes, but still you have only data for the runs and not for the Summary. This task should be done automatically if the VS-SQL integration is correct. After each load_test run, after your Summary report is generated, the data should be exported into the SQL. This was my point. Did you restart the PC? I'm asking since the Excel integration requires such, before you can use them both.

Answer (score 0):

Could you get to database where you saved your result in, should be something in \sqlexpress in default? if only one table, there could be something wrong with Visual Studio. If you didn't get any table from load test, I would suggest you reset your follow this MSDN link and see what you may have missed:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms318550.aspx